# Как передать значение из формы в php код?

Tags: php, form

Использую Payeer для приема платежей. Тестовая форма выглядит следующим образом:

```
<?php
$m_shop = '361276838';
$m_orderid = '1';
$m_amount = "100.00";
$m_curr = 'USD';
$m_desc = base64_encode('Test');
$m_key = 'Ваш секретный ключ';

$arHash = array(
    $m_shop,
    $m_orderid,
    $m_amount,
    $m_curr,
    $m_desc
);


$arHash[] = $m_key;

$sign = strtoupper(hash('sha256', implode(':', $arHash)));
?>
<form method="post" action="https://payeer.com/merchant/">
<input type="hidden" name="m_shop" value="<?=$m_shop?>">
<input type="hidden" name="m_orderid" value="<?=$m_orderid?>">
<input type="text" name="m_amount" value="<?=$m_amount?>">
<input type="hidden" name="m_curr" value="<?=$m_curr?>">
<input type="hidden" name="m_desc" value="<?=$m_desc?>">
<input type="hidden" name="m_sign" value="<?=$sign?>">
<input type="submit" name="m_process" value="send" />
</form>
```

Как значение `m_amount` подставить из формы в формирование сигнатуры `$m_amoun`t?

Comment: Если вам необходимо в форме менять сигнатуру по изменению поля, то вам потребуется javaScript. С стороны сервера вы можете только предопределить свойства полей формы перед отправкой и обработать приходящие из формы данные. Но использование JavaScript полностью невелирует безопасность, т.к. клиенту будет известен хеш ключ.

Answer (score 2):

Взять значение из массива `$_REQUEST` или массивов `$_GET`, `$_POST` в зависимости от метода формы. Например:

```
$m_amount = $_POST['m_amount'];
```

Comment: Ааа, поэтому я и не понял, с чего это вдруг такой вопрос. Тогда удалите ваши комментарии, а на этот мой флаг повесте, чтобы я сюда не возвращался.  PS. А всплывает он потому, что ни на ответе, ни на вопросе плюсов нет.  Я плюсанул, вы плюсанёте, и он больше не будет поднят духом.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы принимаете форму в том же файле то после субмита значение $m_amount из формы можно поймать с помощью:

```
if($_POST['m_amount'] != 'undefined') {
    $m_amount = $_POST['m_amount'];
} else {
    $m_amount = '100.00';
}
```

Comment: Кто-то слишком много программирует на js.